# Leaks in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, xcode4

I'm trying to understand the Leaks Instrument Tool that Xcode4 provides us. The screenshot below shows me a couple of leaks (I think). I was wondering how to read the Leaked object and diagnose where the leak is coming from. Anyone have any suggestions to what [NSPlaceholderMutableString ...] is? I don't have this declared anywhere in the program itself.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. NSPlaceholderMutableString is a private subclass of NSString, which is a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html).
2. See that small little arrow in a circle? Click it couple of times and you'll get to the code (if it's yours). (Last time there will be no arrow, just double-click the row)
3. Read carefully what the titles of the columns and navigation bar say. All info you needed is there ;)

Comment: @adubr thanks. I'm a little bit confused at how I can get to the code. where is the small circle with the arrow?

Comment: Check the selected row in the table. It says:  
    `NSCFString |  | 0xcc5a1b0` **(->)** `| 32 Bytes | blahblahblah`

(sorry I'm not that familiar with markdown yet)

Comment: @adubr yep i clicked on that arrow next to the address, but don't see any code.

Comment: @cfarm54, you should get another table. Then just _double-click_ any row. It will get you to the code **if it was written by you**. If you're trying to get to the Foundation code, for sure it won't let you. Check what's written in the `Responsible library` column.

Comment: @adubr does that mean if i dont see any code the memory leak is false? If so, what causes this false positive?

Comment: Well of course it's possible that the leaks are false, but more likely you're just checking a wrong place, i.e. wrong row in the table. On your screenshot there are 3 leaks which are happening in your code as the Instrument Tools report. Check the lines which have `Hangman` in the `Responsible Library` column. Perhaps you're not releasing some mutable array.